# To detect harmful gases

Tags: pcb-design, esp8266

I’m working on DIY project for my home to detect the harmful gases like CO, CO<sub>2</sub>. I have to design a PCB in which I have included MQ7 for CO and MQ135 for CO<sub>2</sub> and nitrous oxide. I am using Eagle software and I have chosen ESP8266 MCU. My questions are:

1. The MCU I have chosen is good for my project?
2. Can these two sensors work together in the same PCB board?
3. I didn’t find the till what distance these sensor can sense the gases in the environment.

Please help me in designing the board.
Thank you

mq7-https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-7.pdf
mq135-https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/Sensors/Gas/SNS-MQ135/resources/SNS-MQ135.pdf

Comment: You haven't provided links for the gas sensor PDF data sheets.

Comment: Mq7-https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-7.pdf. Mq135-https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/Sensors/Gas/SNS-MQ135/resources/SNS-MQ135.pdf link for sensors

Comment: @Dush. Please [edit] the question and put a tidy link to the datasheet in there where it belongs rather than bury it in the comments. You seem to think that gas concentration is sensed at a distance light a light receiver. It isn't. It's just the gas concentration **in the sensor** so **the sensing distance is zero**.

Comment: Sorry for I didn’t post the link. And understand that it didn’t work with the distance rather than concentration of gases. Thanks. Just was confuse with it.

Answer (score 1):

> The MCU I have chosen is good for my project

The ESP8266 only provides one analog input, you have to either multiplex it, or use another MCU, for example the ESP32 would be a great option!

> I didn’t find the till what distance these sensor can sense the gases in the environment.

Gas Sensors do not work with "distance" they work within a volume of air. To detect the gas concentration in a room for example, you have to know the weight of the gas (lighter or heavier than air) and then place the sensor either on the floor or at the ceiling. If you just want to "detect" gas, it would be good to create a airflow, eg. ventilation.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll use ESP32. And yes with ESP8266 need multiplexer. So with these two sensors and ESP32, nothing else needed i hope. And to power, can i use AA battery? I am want to use usb b type to power and to program the module. Is that ok?

Comment: @Dush: Asking about the battery is expanding the scope of the original question. That's not fair! Instead ask a new question and reference this one if it's relevant. You need to be specific about the number of AA cells you intend to use and, if you can, work out the voltage tolerance of your modules and the likely current required.

Comment: Ok I understand, sorry for this. Just wanted to use 2 AA

Answer (score 0):

> The MCU I have chosen is good for my project?

there is only one analog pin, you probably want two analog pins one for each sensor

> Can these two sensors work together in the same PCB board?

yes, the sensors do not emit anything that would stop each other from working

> I didn’t find the till what distance these sensor can sense the gases in the environment.

traces of the gas must enter the sensor, the datasheet will say at what concentration in air the gas can be sensed.

Comment: So the concentration will be used as a distance? For mq7 it is written that 20-20000ppm so what does it mean? And also the two sensors won’t stop each other so i should start preparing the pcb with esp and these two sensors?

Comment: What do you mean by distance?! The sensor senses the gas concentration at the location where it's placed. There is no strict corellation between "distance" and concentation